# sed emptying file in script

Tags: bash, sed

I have a script to manipulate some log files and then push them up to a server, to be loaded into mysql and analyzed.  I have almost all of this process figured out except the automation of collecting the logs.  I use sed to rip all the `"` out of the log files, so it can more easily be imported into mysql.  When I run the command below it works fine, but run the same command in a shell script, and it creates an empty file.  I am not sure why --any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
sed 's/\"//g' /usr/local/tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.$yest.txt > /$DIR/iweb$yest.txt
```

Here is the complete script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script to manage catalina logs on our servers.

#First create the needed variables.
date=$(date +"%m_%d_%y")
adate=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
yest=$(date -d 'yesterday' +"%Y-%m-%d")
Customer="iwebsup"
log=/isweb/admin/catmanage/log
DIR=/catmanage

#Make Directory
#mkdir /catmanage/tomcat1/

#Run access logs through sed to remove " from file
echo "Removing quote marks from access log and moving to direcotry" &> $log.$date
sed 's/\"//g' "/usr/local/tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.$yest.txt" > "/$DIR/iweb$yest.txt" &> $log.$date
```

Comment: is `$` a literal `$` symbol or variable y?

Comment: $yest is a variable to inject yesterdays date into the file.  The variable is configured to match how tomcat puts the date on access log files

Comment: How about a minimal shell script with same behaviour that other users can test it?

Comment: What happens if you tried `ls /usr/local/tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.$yest.txt` in your script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original question shows redirection with `>` but your actual script has `&>`.  These are rather different things, and in fact, the latter is probably incompatible with your `sh`.

The portable, compatible way to include error redirection is

```
command >file 2>&1
```

Your shebang line says `#!/bin/bash` but based on your diagnostic remarks, I am guessing you are running this with `sh` after all.

By the way, `tr -d '"' <file >newfile` would be a more efficient way to remove double quotes from a file.

Comment: I changed the sed line to use the 2>&1 instead of &> and that solved the issue.  Thank you.

Comment: I’ve just returned to this and see that Deldran’s question has been edited to include the script contents. The problem does indeed lie with the redirection so this answer deserves an up-vote.

Comment: How would you recommend i log this then?  According to the link below &> should send STDOUT and STDEER to a file.  Whenever I put at the end of the sed command it just makes a blank file instead of a file with no ".  I also tried just putting >> after every command to just right stdout to a file and append it.  Still get the same issue and nothing gets written to the file.  http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: I don't see why you anticipate any standard error output from this operation anyway.  Again, the customary way to do that would be `command >>file 2>&1` or with just a single `>` to overwrite an existing file.  (I notice you are overwriting the typo output in your script. :-)

Comment: If indeed there ever is an error message (disk full or whatever), you probably don't want that to land in the data file anyhow.  So maybe just take out the stderr redirection altogether.

Comment: Sorry my mind is not working well for me today.  I undersand with sed there will be no stdout as that creates the file.  doesnt 2>&1 just dump it to /dev/null?  I got my echo's working into the log and that is sufficient for now.  Thanks for all the help

Comment: What? No, `sed` writes to standard output and has no idea that the shell is redirecting that into a file. (Well, maybe some idea, in order to decide whether to do output buffering. With `sed -i` things would be different, but you're not using that.)

Answer (score 2):

Launching a shell script starts a new system process. I suspect that within the context of this script's sub-shell, `$yest` is not set as a shell variable. If you're going to use `$yest` in a shell-script, you should ideally pass its value as an argument to the script -- or alternatively export the shell variable as an environment variable (`export $yest`) which will be inherited by the sub-shell process (all child processes inherit the environment of their parent process).

When debugging shell scripts, it's always useful to include `set -xvu` at the start of the section that you're debugging so that you can see what the script is doing and what values are stored in its variables.

```
  -x  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.
  -v  Print shell input lines as they are read.
  -u  Treat unset variables as an error when substituting.
```

You can turn off this debugging by later running `set -xvu`.

Comment: I updated the OP with the complete script.  I define the variable $yest inside the script,  i have done this in several other scripts that run in chron without issue.